# Missing eCommerce data

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Just noticed the following message in google analytics "Property xx is configured for Ecommerce, but no transaction data is being received. Your site may not be tagged for Ecommerce."

The site has had ecommerce data for several years using GA although we plan to upgrade to UA very soon. We haven't made any changes to the site or GA snippet. Has anyone else received this message or can shed any light as to why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninjasys,

You also have to send the website's transaction data with the other information in your google analytics tracking data.

E.g.:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']); // This must be the ID of the Google Analytics account to send the data to.
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); // Sends a page view to Google Analytics.
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
```

The full code you can find [here](http://www.fresheggdigital.com.au/blog/web-development-2/how-to-set-up-e-commerce-tracking-in-google-analytics)